# Dependable drop down list in JSP, Struts2

Tags: struts2

i am working on a project and using Struts2 for it with JSP. In one JSP page, i have two drop down list say dd1 and dd2. The dd2 is dependable on dd1. The values in dd2 should be populated based on the dd1 value. Now i have a java class which gives me all the options for the drop down lists from the database and i am displying them in my JSP using the SELECT tag. How to make the dd2 dependable on dd1? I dont have any knowledge of Ajax. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very big fan of any Ajax plugin.If you do not want to use any big fancy Ajax tags and are ready to learn a bit of JQuery or any other java-script framework, i suggest you to use simple ajax call.

Play around with the events when the value in your parent drop-down change call a function and make an Ajax call to your action which can return the values in JSON format (use [struts2 JSON plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html)), parse the JSON data and fill the other drop-down.

benefits of this approach are

1. More flexible.
2. Much light and faster.
3. No need to add any UN-necessary dependencies. Other approach (IMO not the good one) use Struts2-Jquery plugin to get it done but get ready for any undesirable behavior or any other issue and you have to reply on the Plugin community.

Here is an example as suggested

```
<s:select list="states" label="State" name="state" onchange="ajaxCallForDistrict();"
id="stateList"></s:select>
<s:select list="districts" label="District" name="district" id="district" />
```

what i am doing here is that District are dependent upon state so once user select a State from first select i am calling a java-script function on `onchange` event and here is my `ajaxCallForDistrict()` function

```
function ajaxCallForDistrict()
{ 

        var selectedState = document.getElementById("stateList");
        var statedata = selectedState.options[selectedState.selectedIndex].value;
        var formInput='state='+statedata;       
        $.getJSON('search/getDistricts',formInput,function(data) {
            $('.result').html('' + data.districts + '');
            $.each(data.districts,function(index, value){
            var districtid = document.getElementById("district");
            var option=new Option(value,value);
            try{
                districtid.add(option);
            }
            catch(e){
                districtid.appendChild(option);
            }
            });
            });
    }
```

what i am doing in above function is that i am fetching the value of selected state and giving the Ajax call to `getDistricts` Action which is simply creating a list of district for the provided state and returning back the result as JSON data.
for filling the District select i am looping through the result (JSON) and appending the element in the select box

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please provide some sample code

Comment: It would help if you provided some code to suggest what you are doing.  Some html that would be the end result would be a good start along with a description of where it is coming from.

Comment: @Quaternion: agree!!! but i believe a small Google search will help a lot.But i am fully agree that an explanation with a small code is more powerful than simple words

Comment: I'm sorry Umesh, good answer +1 but I meant the OP aught to have added some sample code...

Comment: @Quaternion :) i Though you have asked me and it was good suggestion either way.

Answer (score 0):

JSP are servlets inside so there no way how to make interaction after response is send to client

i would recommend [struts2-jquery-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) - you will be able to solve this problem using ajax and this framework is good place to start if you are not interested in learning javascript (jQuery), [showcase](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please provide some sample code

Comment: there is showcase link in my response - there you can find a low of examples

Comment: It is easier to just use jQuery.  We get a lot of "how do I do X with the strus2-jquery-plugin" and all the serious web programmers use JS (and what ever framework of choice). The plugin is far too limited (arguably any ajax based tag library) so the result is that the OP will experience more frustration down this path.

Comment: yes its limited and yes it is better to use jquery+ json plugin but its a lot of new things to learn in his actual situation , isnt it better to see personally that it very limited but he will get at least some overview about what to do, do you think its better to just copy paste jQuery example from somewhere - in this case ( dropdown ) framework will do the job - it is not good to say yeah man learn 1,2,3 techs a then you will have you dropdown ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but may be this can help you...

jsp page

```
<s:select name= "" lable = "" onchange="javaScriptFunction(element that you have selected);"></s:select>
```

JavaScript---

```
<script>
     function javaScriptFunction(element)
    {

        document.LoginForm.action=element+".action";
        document.LoginForm.submit();
    }

</script>
```

Now map these action in struts.xml
My suggestion is use one action but several different methods.
After that populate the other dropdown Box by using `s:iterator`.